# Structure of the reward function for an MDP

Tags: markov-process, reinforcement-learning

I have a system where there are initial states and successor states but no actions - all transitions occur according to the transition matrix. I have 8 states total and wondered what the form of the reward function would be? Is it an 8x8 matrix where each row shows the rewards of moving from state $s$ to state $s'$?

In what scenarios is the reward function a vector?